# What is the difference between a REPL and an interpreter?

Tags: interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

Is there any technical difference between a REPL and an interpreter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interactive interpreters use REPLs. An interpreter is not required to have one. You can run Python, for example, in non-interactive mode (on a file) and it will not use a read-eval-print loop.