# Relation between REPL, interpreter and compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop):

> The REPL is commonly misnamed an
>   interpreter. This is a misnomer—many
>   programming languages that use
>   compilation (including bytecode
>   compilation) have REPLs, such as
>   Common Lisp and Python.

From [a reply to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424756/what-is-the-difference-between-a-repl-and-an-interpreter/3424772#3424772)

> Interactive interpreters use REPLs. An
>   interpreter is not required to have
>   one. You can run Python, for example,
>   in non-interactive mode (on a file)
>   and it will not use a read-eval-print
>   loop.

I was wondering if REPL [del] always exists [/del] **exists only** for an interpreter? Does Wikipedia say REPL also exists for a compiler? If yes, how is that like?

Thanks and regards!

By interpreter, I mean the one perform execution immediately after compilation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether you are asking for the words commonly used or something else.

In any case, a REPL is a Read Eval Print Loop (see first letters).
If you have an interpreter that doesn't read your program or doesn't evaluate it (i.e. "understand" what you want it to do and do it) or doesn't print the results anywhere, what good is it?

If you wouldn't see anything at all and it wouldn't hear you it wouldn't do what you want anyway or you only had 1 try you could as well put a rock on the table instead of the computer.

Maybe there could be funny playing-with-words objections like "if it only changes an icon that is displayed, is it really printing?" and such :-)
Or "if it isn't reading from the keyboard, is it really reading?". 
Silly pure philosophy, really.

What's true is that some systems react differently depending on whether you make them read from the keyboard or from a file. I'm not sure what the use of that is, but I guess you could offer help to the human (i.e. command completion etc) when he's actually typing on the keyboard.

Maybe some don't accept more than 1 expression when reading from a file?

> I was wondering if REPL always exists for an interpreter?

I guess its a question of the definition of "interpreter". If you take it to mean (in the pragmatic sense) "something that does what I tell it to do", no. How would you tell it if it won't listen?

> Does Wikipedia say REPL also exists for a compiler? If yes, how is that like?

Yes, of course. All LISP systems are like that.
They feel exactly like an interpreter but stuff just gets magically faster over time as the system learns how you phrase yourself and learns what changes and what doesn't and just compiles what doesn't change to machine code.

Java also does that nowadays, the longer your VM session lasts the more it finds out how to make things faster and if you stop changing things it will eventually end up running the entire program in machine code.

The whole artificial distinction of interpreter/compiler came to be accidentially, that is to say, because of resource constraints back in the day.

Comment: Thanks! Is interpreter defined as one performs execution immediately after compilation? I thought it this way.

Comment: The distinction interpreter/compiler is really not there, it's just an artifact of old times like the pyramids or how people still measure things in foot. Simple interpreters just read what you want and then immediately did it. Over time, people got annoyed with waiting and so it was extended to just remember answers so it didn't sit there thinking it all out from the beginning every time. Some eventually stopped doing anything immediately and just compiled everything, some do both, some switch depending on how the load is (how busy it is).

Comment: Say you give to a C compiler "int x = 5+2;" if it would interpret it as "create a program that will, upon execution, take 5 and add 2 to it and store the result in the variable x [which is an integer, duh]", that would be very strange. What actually happens that even C, interprets. It will create a program that will, upon execution, store the value 7 into x. Or even it will create a program that has a variable x which has the value 7 in the executable image and it will do nothing at all pertaining to that when you run it. In C++ any calc. can be done at compile time if values are available.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe not a good answer, just some notes,

- JavaScript in IE 6.0 doesn't come with a REPL.
- REPL for compilers maybe look like interpreters as well, if the language can be parsed in one time, forward only. The compiler may insert breakpoint after each compiled statement, do the execution until it reaches the breakpoint, then returned back to user, wait for the next input line, and repeat. Finally, all input lines are compiled, and executed as well.

Comment: Thanks! so in the second case, is a compiler with REPL always an interpreter?

Comment: @Tim: A compiler is not an interpreter, regardless of whether it is used to build a REPL.

Comment: @Tim, no, for example there is no interpreter at all in SBCL, only a compiler, but still there is a decent REPL.

Comment: @delnan: Thanks! Is interpreter defined as one performs execution immediately after compilation? I thought it this way.

Comment: @Tim: I think not, in the second case, the compiler doesn't interpret, it just compiles, and let CPU to do the interpreting, so it's not an interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

REPL stands for Read-Eval-Print-Loop. Both an interpreter and a compiler can be used to do the `eval` bit - either have an instance of the interpreter running in the background and feed it the input, or use the compiler to compile incrementally (granted, this takes much more work and some cooperation from the compiler writers, but it's possible, as countless instances show - you generally only compile to bytecode though). The rest is mostly I/O and some glue to keep all the previously entered definitions available for the next commands.