# Applications of REPL process in development

Tags: java, heroku, read-eval-print-loop

Now I am reading Heroku's documents and I have a question about how to use REPL process in development.  The statement I have roadblocks in is this one.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#start-a-one-off-dyno

" It can also be used to launch a REPL process attached to your local terminal for experimenting in your app’s environment, or code that you deployed with your application"

I know we have almost same questions of how a REPL process applies to it in stackoverflow that is  [What's a REPL process and what can I use it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731782/whats-a-repl-process-and-what-can-i-use-it-for).
However, I can't understand the answer because the question's language is Node.js , which I am not familiar with unfortunately.   So, could you translate the answer to the one which uses other words? I know Java. So, I hope you will use the terminology related to Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't have a REPL in release yet, in Java 9+ it will be [JShell](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/jshell-and-repl-in-java-9). REPL is short for Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop and is a hallmark of an interpreted language (Java is compiled). But, REPLs are so useful they are adding one.

```
efrisch@eeyore ~ $ jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9-ea
|  For an introduction type: /help intro


jshell> /help intro
|  
|  intro
|  
|  The jshell tool allows you to execute Java code, getting immediate results.
|  You can enter a Java definition (variable, method, class, etc), like:  int x = 8
|  or a Java expression, like:  x + x
|  or a Java statement or import.
|  These little chunks of Java code are called 'snippets'.
|  
|  There are also jshell commands that allow you to understand and
|  control what you are doing, like:  /list
|  
|  For a list of commands: /help

jshell> for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   ...> System.out.println(i);
   ...> }

0
1
2
3
```

Comment: So, basically you can't give me any good explanation about above statement Heroku said because Java is a compile type language. Right?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita Because the Java REPL isn't in general release yet. You could download Java 9 (beta), launch jshell and just type in some code (and run it as you type it, line by line). Scala and Groovy are both generally available, and both run in the JVM, and both have a REPL.

Comment: Thank you. I understand I don't need it until I am able to handle an other language. But could you explain what the statement actually means?

Comment: It means read, evaluate, print, loop. So, you open a repl. You type `System.out.println(2+2);` and press enter you get `4` and then a prompt to enter another line (to run)..